# Meteor reports 500 errors randomly

Tags: post, meteor, websocket, iron-router

I am running Meteor 1.2.1 but this issue has occurred on 1.1 as well. It seems to happen pretty randomly. I tend to notice it if I take focus off the window that I start seeing them appear more regularly. This is the error that I see:

```
sockjs-0.3.4.js:854 POST http://blah.something.com/sockjs/770/bh33bcip/xhr 500 (Internal Server Error)
AbstractXHRObject._start @ sockjs-0.3.4.js:854
(anonymous function) @ sockjs-0.3.4.js:881
```

I recently installed natestrauser:connection-banner which pops a banner at the top when Meteor.connection.status().status is anything other than "connected". Since I installed it, this pops up every time I see the 500 error. The 500 error seems to kick it into "waiting" status. It reconnects eventually, but it's a rather annoying error.

I don't see anything on the server side whatsoever, nor on the client side. Does anyone have ideas on how to debug this, or why I'm getting this error?

A picture is included here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V827N.jpg

Comment: This is too broad. You could try to isolate the issue by removing components and debugging. Without the code or any other clues, the chances of anyone getting the right answer are slim, in my opinion.

Comment: That's a fair point, but this issue started early on with mostly vanilla plugins. I will try a fresh instance, but if that has the issue too, then I have no real idea on where to begin debugging this. There are no logs either on the server or client side that point to what the issue is other than something to do with sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem! I use pound as a reverse proxy and the default installation has a very short timeout. I changed that timeout from 15 seconds to 60 seconds and the 500 errors disappeared. I don't know if this is because pound's keep alive was set to 30 (which would likely not keep anything alive given that the timeout was 15 seconds), or if its because the Meteor client doesn't check in more frequently than 15 seconds. Perhaps someone can chime in as to why this?

Either way, beware of your reverse proxy settings with Meteor!